# how can I access files in the internal storage's root directory?

Tags: android

My device has no SD card, but I can access the files of "Internal storage" in Windows explorer, in which there is a "tmp.txt".

[image]

The txt file was pasted via Windows explorer, now I want to read this file. My codes are:

```
    File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    File file = new File(sdcard,"tmp.txt");

    StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();
    try {
        InputStream in = new FileInputStream(file);
        ...
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
    }
```

But it's not working, it step to catch exception after `new FileInputStream(file);`, the debug information logs the file location actually is `"/storage/emulated/0/tmp.txt"`, so it couldn't find the file. 
Then I tried put the file in the Download directory using:

```
File fileDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);
File file = new File(fileDir, "tmp.txt");
```

error log:[exception e:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SrPqj.png)

It's not working either, basically they are the same problem. Can I access files in this directory?

Comment: Do you have the permissions set in Android Manifest that allow to read storage?

Comment: What exception? Please provide error log.

Comment: @Dhaval Patel, e = "java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/tmp.txt: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)"

Comment: @Krzysztof Kubicki, I had permissions added:    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />

Comment: read this: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage You don't have the permission to read the storage, the permissions you put are for location services.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read this: developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage You don't have the permission to read the storage, the permissions you put are for location services.